# activeadmin dropdown pass values with helper method to collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How can I use the helper method on the show page to display apple instead of op1?

This example uses a helper method to pass in the values to the collection.
"op1" is saved in db and "apple" is displayed in the dropdown.

[image]

**app/admin/example.rb**

```
form do
  f.input :name, :as => :select, :collection => test_method
end 

show do
   attributes_table_for example do
       row("Name") { example.name }
   end
end
```

**examples_helper.rb**

```
def test_method
   hash = {"apple"  => "op1",
           "orange" => "op2",
           "berry"  => "op3"}
   hash
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the hash variable in the ActiveRecord model as a constant. Then you can use:

```
attributes_table_for example do
       row("Name") { MyModel::HASH_CONSTANT[example.name.to_sym] }
   end
```

The hash should be `op1: "apple"` pairs, not `"apple"  => "op1"`

Comment: how do you convert the hash to symbol for the dropdown?
:collection => MyModel::HASH_CONSTANT

Comment: MyModel::HASH_CONSTANT.map {|key, value| [value, key]}